# What's the preferred python distribution if I want to package my env and code into one bundle

Tags: python, python-packaging

I have a python env and code that runs on that env. I have code to setup this env using wget and such, but that's not OS independent really.

I wish to bundle this env and code into one (bundle?) and distribute, so the user doesn't has to set up the env before running the code.

Basically give the end user something (executable, tar, zip, .py), and after running/extracting that user should be able to run my main python script.

I looked into wheels, but I'm not sure if that solves the purpose.

Comment: Did you consider virtualenv's?

Comment: that's what I use to create the env for development, but that won't bundle the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). Seems straightforward and under active development.

Answer (score 1):

If the code is run on a server you should consider using [docker](https://www.docker.com) and [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/).

This technology allows you to define the entire setup in config-files, and the only thing you need to do when you deploy your code on a new server is to run a single command (`docker-compose up`)

Comment: Mostly the code won't be running on servers. Doesn't work for me :(